# Can we touch the shivling to spread the contents of the offering like curd or ghee around it while doing Abhishek?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam, puja

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Puja that -

> Fingers should not be put in water, milk and ghee etc., because the touching of nails makes these things inauspicious.

But when I offer curd and ghee in Abhishek with just a spoon, without touching the offering with my hand, the consistency of the substances makes them pile up at the top without properly flowing down the shivling. The result is a mound of offering on the top and none of it spread uniformly. So can I massage the shivling by hand while doing Abhishek to smoothen out the offerings? It can be compared to bathing a child with soap, or applying some herbal unguent on their body, for their own benefit. We don't just squeeze the lotion out, we rub it onto their skin for a good distribution. Is this allowed with the shivling?

Comment: In Kashi I believe its allowed!

Comment: Why shouldn't be allowed? Do you think that one should not touch the Shivalinga or what?

Comment: @Rickross I don't know f touching the offering is allowed. It is usually offered using a utensil, and I have never seen anyone touching it after it has been offered on the shivling.

Comment: When you are allowed to consume the Padodakam/Charanamrita itself then what is the problem in touching it? @TigerShroff

Comment: @Rickross The problem is touching something which is in contact with Lord Shiva while it is _on_ Lord Shiva ie. while Lord Shiva is consuming it. The charanamrita is a remnant of the food He has already consumed. So they are two different things.

Comment: Going by that logic we shd keep the nirmalya on the Linga for ever. But in fact we need to wash it as quickly as possible. Also Lord Shiva does not consume the products that are offered onto the Linga while bathing. He consumes only the Naivedyam that is offered. Moreover, Charanmrita does not mean remnants of food consumed by Shiva, it means the things which has touched the Lingam like water, curd, honey etc. @TigerShroff

Comment: @How soon should the nirmalaya be washed? I have read 15-20 minutes. And I should've specified, my problem is that anything that Lord Shiva is _using_, that is in contact with him, can we touch it while it is on him?

Comment: @Rickross What is your source that the things which have touched shivling can be consumed? Here it says - http://shivalingapuja.blogspot.com/2011/08/special-thanks-to-capt-js-chauhan-and.html - nirmalaya "is forbidden to be consumed"

Comment: My source is various scriptures not blogspots like those (I already hv an answer on that). Also if I am not mistaken you too hv also written answer regarding that Charanmrita can be consumed. @TigerShroff

Comment: Better to check the Mahashivaratri Puja by Sringeri Shankacharya or his Chandramauliswara Pujas on Youtube. You will get an idea about how things are done. @TigerShroff

Comment: @Rickross I have written an answer where Swami Sivananda says it can be consumed but I am not sure whether it is correct or not. I was just adding a source I found. I read your answer though, that satisfies me. Thanks for the youtube recommendations.

Comment: @Community Why not to move this to chat? Moderator attention solicited

Comment: @Vineet part of the discussion is asking for the clarification from OP.